# SQL Server : LAG multiple Nulls

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, repeat, lag

I am trying to "fill in the blanks" with my table below.

I have created a PDF reader that spits out a JSON file that I have manipulated into the below format.

There is very little scope in changing source data, or using a secondary table as a helper, due to the fact that this is meant to handle new data not "seen" before.

What I need help with is getting the `Class` and `Group` columns filled in. By this I mean that the Class Column will always have a value in the last row, and I need this repeated (upwards) until it comes across a non-blank value in the column. It then needs to repeat this value, until it comes across the next non-blank and so on.

Similarly the Group Column needs the same solution but starting from the first row down.

I have tried `LAG()` `LEAD()` etc with default values, but it doesn't handle the multiple `nulls`.

I also need the `Group` column to show the class value when not blank.

I have had a look at cte's but not overly familiar with them and have gotten myself tied in knots today!

Any help is appreciated.

Current Data

```
ID, Class, Group, Total, Account
1, null, INCOME, null, Fencing
2, null, null, null, Crop
3, Net Income, null, null, Net Income
4, null, Farm Expenditure, null, Irrigation
5, null, null, null, electricity
6, Surplus, null, null, Surplus
7, null, GST, null, GST
8, Closing Balance, null, null, Closing Balance
```

What I want

```
ID, Class, Group, Total, Account
1, Net Income, INCOME, null, Fencing
2, Net Income, INCOME, null, Crop
3, Net Income, INCOME, null, Net Income
4, Surplus, Farm Expenditure, null, Irrigation
5, Surplus, Farm Expenditure, null, electricity
6, Surplus, Farm Expenditure, null, Surplus
7, Closing Balance, GST, null, GST
8, Closing Balance, GST, null, Closing Balance
```

Comment: please do not post image, use text instead. Please include some sample data, expected result and your attempt

Comment: You also need to provide more details than simply: "What I need help with is getting the Class and Group columns filled in.". How do you want them filled in? What are the rules and criteria.

Comment: *"sorry guys, cant edit my question so cant post the text."* Yes you can, *any one* can [edit] the question, including you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you the output you want with the data you give. In your sample data there is only one "group" in each "class", but it looks like there could maybe be multiple groups per class? If that is the case, it will be a bit more complicated, but the principal will be the same.

```
CREATE TABLE #data (ID INT, Class VARCHAR(50), [Group] VARCHAR(50), Total INT, Account VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #data(ID, Class, [Group], Total, Account) VALUES
(1, null, 'INCOME', null, 'Fencing'),
(2, null, null, null, 'Crop'),
(3, 'Net Income', null, null, 'Net Income'),
(4, null, 'Farm Expenditure', null, 'Irrigation'),
(5, null, null, null, 'electricity'),
(6, 'Surplus', null, null, 'Surplus'),
(7, null, 'GST', null, 'GST'),
(8, 'Closing Balance', null, null, 'Closing Balance');

-- Find the break points that signify the end of a Class
WITH breaks as(
    SELECT IIF(Class IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS breakpoint, ID, Class, [Group], Total, Account 
    FROM #data
),
-- count the breakpoints passed so each group will have a number we can group by
grp AS (
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(breakpoint) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS grp, 
    ID,Class,[Group],Total,Account
FROM breaks
)
SELECT MAX(grp.Class) OVER (PARTITION BY grp.grp) AS Class,
    MAX(grp.[Group]) OVER (PARTITION BY grp.grp) AS [Group],
    grp.Total,
    grp.Account
FROM grp
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much James! I will make a couple of tweaks to it, and then post the final code. This works really well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks To James, I have now tweaked his code to give the correct Group, as the class and group needed different logic.

```
-- Find the break points that signify the end of a Class
WITH classbreaks as(
    SELECT IIF(Class IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS breakpoint, ID, Class, [Group], Total, Account 
    FROM [PedGroup_db].[dbo].[Cashflow]
),

-- Find the break points that signify the end of a Group
grpbreaks as(
    SELECT IIF([Group] IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS breakpoint, ID, Class, [Group], Total, Account 
    FROM [PedGroup_db].[dbo].[Cashflow]
),

-- count the breakpoints passed so each class will have a number we can group by
clss AS (
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(breakpoint) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS grp, 
    ID,Class,[Group],Total,Account
FROM classbreaks

),

-- count the breakpoints passed so each group will have a number we can group by
grp AS (
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(breakpoint) OVER (ORDER BY ID),0) AS grp, 
    ID,Class,[Group],Total,Account
FROM grpbreaks

)

--join the two sub queries together on ID
SELECT MAX(clss.Class) OVER (PARTITION BY clss.grp) AS Class,
    case when clss.Class = grp.Account Then grp.Account else MAX(grp.[Group]) OVER (PARTITION BY grp.grp) end AS [Group],
    grp.Total,
    grp.Account
FROM clss left join grp on grp.ID = clss.ID
```